# Do drafts work?

Tags: statistics, draft

YouTube recently gave me some video suggestions that I watched.  Basically, it was the worst draft picks of all time, worst #1 picks, best underrated draft picks, etc.  Is there any statistics that show high draft picks improve a team in the short and/or long term?

Ive been googling, but I cant find anything.  Maybe Im using the wrong search terms.

Answer (score 1):

Picks in higher rounds do better by staying in the league longer, starting more, and being more likely to be Pro-Bowlers.

According to [forbes.com](https://www.forbes.com/sites/prishe/2015/05/22/tracking-nfl-draft-efficiency-how-contingent-is-success-to-draft-position/#609ec1d17495),
of starters in the NFL in 2014,

> Nearly 30% of all starters were 1st round draft picks when drafted into the league;
>
> -Roughly 30% were taken in either the 2nd or 3rd round;
>
> -Roughly 26% were taken in either rounds 4 through 7;
>
> -Undrafted players (14%) were the 3rd most likely group to comprise 2014’s starters…only behind 1st round (30%) and 2nd round (18%) picks.
>
> [image: Correlation between Draft Position and "Starter Status"]
>
> -The overall median “percentage of games started” by those players selected in the 2010 NFL Draft is 15%;
>
> -1st round draftees from that season started a higher median percentage of games (67.5%) compared to players drafted in other rounds;
>
> -2nd and 3rd round draftees from 2010 have started roughly 34% and 36% of all possible games, respectively.
>
> -The median percentage of games started for players drafted in rounds 4 through 7 from the 2010 draft was extremely low, never rising above 7% of games played over the last 5 years.
>   [image: Correlation between Draft Position and Staying Power]
>
> -48.5% were first round draft picks when they entered the league;
>
> -2nd round picks were the next most likely to reach All-Pro status (14%);
>
> -But then undrafted players were the third most likely at 10.5%;
>
> -Lastly, 21% of All-Pros from this period came from either the 3rd, 4th, or 5th round.
>   [image: Correlation between Draft Position and Reaching "All-Pro" Status]